# Apply Maven mirror to archetypes

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

In my settings.xml, I redirected everything to my own repository by setting

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://dox4453:8084/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

But when I use the `archetype:generate`, I get a warning:

```
[WARNING] Error reading archetype catalog http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
```

Does this mirroring not apply to archetypes? Or is there something that can overwrite the mirror settings?

Comment: What is the Maven command you launched? Can you try with adding `-DarchetypeRepository="local"`?

Comment: DarchetypeRepository="local" does nothing.  I launched "mvn archetype:generate". Do I need to explicitly set the archetype repository even if I have a mirror?